# Select List values not visible - but while on debug its visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select element with values adding up to it using a javascript function  which also has a value selected by default.

Everything is fine when i use the google chrome debug mode to see what has gone wrong. If i come out of the debug mode, i cant see any values, even though they are loaded.

They seem to turn back when i scroll using the select elements.

Everything seems fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox though.

Anyone faced this issue before?

Adding the code here: function call has only first 3 variables set. childSelect1 is the select element i am talking about and childOptions1 are the available options for it. The options are added based on the value in parentSelect.

```
function toggleChildOptions(parentSelect, childSelect1, childOptions1, childSelect2, childOptions2, addBlankEntry)
{
    if(childSelect1 == null && childSelect2 == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(childSelect1 != null)
    {
        childSelect1.options.length = 0;
    }
    if(childSelect2 != null)
    {   
        childSelect2.options.length = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < parentSelect.length; i++)
    {
        if(parentSelect.options[i].selected)
        {
            var parentID = parentSelect.options[i].value;
            if(childSelect1 != null)
            {
                var currentChildOption1Length = childSelect1.options.length;
                if (addBlankEntry == true)
                    childSelect1.options[currentChildOption1Length++] = new Option('',-1);
                for(var j = 0; j<childOptions1.length;j++)
                {   
                    if(childOptions1[j][1] == parentID)
                    {               
                            childSelect1.options[currentChildOption1Length++] = new Option(childOptions1[j][2],childOptions1[j][0]);
                        if (childOptions1[j][2] == '')
                            child1BlankFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(childSelect2 != null)
            {
                var currentChildOption2Length = childSelect2.options.length;
                if (addBlankEntry == true)
                    childSelect2.options[currentChildOption2Length++] = new Option('',-1);
                for(var v = 0; v<childOptions2.length; v++)
                {   
                    if(childOptions2[v][1] == parentID)
                    {
                      childSelect2.options[currentChildOption2Length++] = new Option(childOptions2[v][2],childOptions2[v][0]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the code in the question.

Comment: sorry, but it's too late now.